# Rails 7 - selecting database with multi-database when calling ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-on-rails-6.1

The new multi-database feature is great, however it is unclear to me how you can still execute raw mysql calling ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute and have it select a specific database in the database.yml file.

this

ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) do

end
Doesnt accept a database

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute  always seems to USE the first database in the config file.
thanks

Tried: ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to do ...
doesn't expect a database

Comment: Protip - don't use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`. Instead call `connection` on your own model. That way you can do per model database configuration if needed without refactoring.

Comment: yup - that's how you do it! thanks